# facebook search api json decode in php

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to search the facebook api for keywords, which I can do successfully, however the results returned are in a json array and I need to decode the individual post and extract data from that. This is the code I am using to search the api:

```
$q = "xxxx"; // dont need to urlencode the string
$q = str_replace(" ","+",$q); 
$search = $facebook->api('/search?q='.$q.'&type=post&limit=500');
```

If I was just hitting a URL I would use the json_decode function of PHP but I cant use it in this instance, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If it returns a JSON you should be able to use the json_decode. Are you getting a error or what is the exact issue with the reulst returned.

Comment: the error i get is PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: It appears to be your result is an array. can you dump/ email a part of the result string.

Comment: whats your email and ill email it across

Comment: done now, this is an example

Comment: or else sent to kasun_likemoonatyahoodotcom